# One website, two public IPs, each IP on separate line, how to do failover

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, asp.net, failover, website

We have a website that sits behind two firewalls, main and failover. Main and failover firewall have different IPs, and different Internet connections from different providers. How to provide failover when main failover or main internet connection dies that clients automatically connect to website over second IP?

The failover over of firewalls works, they are both stateful. It is not important which model, lets imagine that they work.

We know that we can go in DNS and manually change the website IP to failover IP, but is there a more elegant and faster solution?

Comment: Why manually hange DNS ? Why not use dynamic DNS ?

Comment: You mean a software or a service like no-ip? If service then that means that we have to move all our DNS records? If software then whcih one? Tnx

Comment: I mean service. Sometimes you can avoid moving records. Subscribe to some cheap dynamic DNS and you get a domain name like yourname.dynamidnsprovider.net, which (once you setup updater software) resolves to your currently active IP. Now, if your website is www.example.com, you create at your _existing_ DNS, record www.example.com CNAME yourname.dynamidnsprovider.net. Mission accomplished. Will not work for zone apex though.

Answer (score 5):

> We know that we can go in DNS and manually change the website IP to failover IP, but is there a more elegant and faster solution?

Not unless a) both your providers support BGP and b) they'd be willing to advertise your routes and c) you have your own ASN.  Otherwise DNS is your only option.  It's not a horrible choice though if you set your TTL really low and using one of the smarter DNS provider that can redirect traffic based on non-responsive ping.  CloudFlare is also an option if your site is primarily static information that can be cached and served to users in the event of an outage.

Really though, if you truly need this level of HA, you should be hosting in a datacenter.

Comment: No need for "smarter DNS providers" in this case simple dynamic DNS would do all the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options but I would suggest a loadbalancer like F5 - it uses pools with a virtual IP address and the pool contains members which in this case is your webservers. It is able to determine if a webserver is up by looking for a string on a page. If the web server is down, the F5 marks the member down, so only traffic goes to the member which is available. In your case, you would have an active and passive set up possibly, with a health check looking for a internet connection out. If it goes down, the loadbalance will mark the member down. Your dns record will sit on at the pool level on the load balancer.

This is also available using linux and HA proxy, if you can't afford an F5. Have a look here http://haproxy.1wt.eu/ or here http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-high-availability-load-balancer-with-haproxy-keepalived-on-debian-lenny. Search on line for HA proxy. We use this in our environment and we are a global service provider.